# Specifying range criteria without the use of a structured table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working on a table that holds the total amount for products sold or bought in the total column with a reference column that refers to the product id which the total points to.

I need to mark of those products for which the total amount (debit/received) calculates to 0 for each product reference.

For this, I am currently using structured table references to specify the range in my SUMIFS formula like this

```
=ROUND(SUMIFS([Total],[Reference],[@Reference]),2)=0
```

Could you please help with how to do the same using the range instead of table references as in

```
=ROUND(SUMIFS(AD:AD,AC:AC, ..............),2)=0
```

Please help me on how to write the formula in this case.

Comment: before u down vote a question please please please point out the reason for doing so. It might help us with modifying our question to get better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enter this at a given row, say row 2:

```
=ROUND(SUMIFS(AD:AD,AC:AC,AC2),2)=0
'                          ^^^ The row you type in
```

and then copy/paste in the cells below; the row number will automatically adjust for each row.